# can spring roo parse variables in arguments of annotation @javax.validation.constraints.Size?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-roo

i have a spring roo application with an entity **Book**. the entity has some properties like **title** where i use a variable **ONE_KILO_BYTE** as value:

```
public class Book {

 private static final int ONE_KILO_BYTE = 1024;

 @NotNull
 @Size(max = ONE_KILO_BYTE)
 private String title;
 ...
}
```

the code compiles and works well, but in spring roo shell i get some errors and the corresponding aj file like Book_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj can no more be updated by the roo shell. the error message in spring roo shell looks like this:

```
org.springframework.roo.model.EnumDetails cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

when i replace all occurences of **ONE_KILO_BYTE** with **1024** spring roo is able to generate aj files again.

roo version: 1.2.5.RELEASE

my problem remembers me a bit of this issue:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3047

is it possible to use constant values in @Size annotation arguments with spring roo?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible. The reason is that Roo MetaModel needs the value for generating code.